# How to save google-services.json file

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I'm trying to connect my app to firebase. What do I need to do to save the google-services.json file? My computer automatically download it to text file (I uploaded the pic of the download). How to open and download it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `google-services.json` file is indeed a text file. But you don't need to open or read it. All you have to do is drag it from explorer/finder into the app folder of your app in Android Studio. From there on, the Android app will automatically find the file when it builds the app.

If you're having problems with this, you might be better served by using the Firebase Assistant that is built into Android Studio. Go to the Tools menu and then click Firebase.

Comment: when I try to drag it from the explorer (the blue google-services.json link) to the android studio (projects src) it doesn't let me drug - it shows a black sign of  no entry  sign